# scale dependent rendering of base layers(gmap,ghyb) causes warping/flickering

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

Hey guys I am using geoserver to host my WMS layers and I am using gmaps base layers in Openlayers. Below I have attempted to use scale dependent rendering of the base layer without any luck.
 What I am trying to do is once the user zooms past a certain level, Google's hybrid map will turn off and Google's aerial will turn on.....With the code I have now it will turn on and off but it tends to warp the base map or flicker. Not sure whats going on.

```
            /*map.events.on({ "zoomend": function (e) {
            if (this.getZoom() > 16) {
              gmap.setVisibility(false);
              ghyb.setVisibility(true);
            }
            else {
              gmap.setVisibility(false);
              ghyb.setVisibility(true);
            }
          }
        });*/
```